# ¿Cómo puedo abrir el explorador de archivos para seleccionar una ruta en C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

Estoy haciendo una ventana en WPF de Visual Studio que será parte de un instalador y lo que quiero es que al presionar un botón se abra el explorador de archivos para poder seleccionar una ruta, pero lo único que he logrado es que se me abra el explorador pero sin opción a seleccionar una ruta, esto lo he logrado con el comando `System.Diagnotics.Process.Start("c:");`. No se si falta algo más o existe otro comando para lograr mi objetivo. Esto es lo que quiero lograr:
[image: Así debería quedarme]

Gracias por la ayuda ofrecida.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes hacer uso de la clase FolderBrowserDialog de System.Windows.Forms el cual te permite abrir una ventana donde escoger un directorio. Como estas trabajando en WPF ese ensamblado no esta incluido te recomiendo que lo agregues haciendo haciendo click encima de tus referencias en la ventana de **Explorador de soluciones** y marques la opción **Agregar Referencias**, se abrirá una ventana y ahi buscas la pestaña **Ensamblados** (en el VStudio 2017 es la primera) y en la lista que se muestra a tu izquierda buscas el elemento que se llame **System.Windows.Forms** y lo seleccionas, ya por último das Aceptar y ya puedes programar usando este ensamblado.

Aquí te dejo el código.

Agrega el ensamblado en tus using

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

Este es el evento click de tu botón

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        using(var fd = new FolderBrowserDialog())
        {
            if(fd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fd.SelectedPath))
            {
                textBox1.Text = fd.SelectedPath;
            }
        }
    }
```

Lo que hago en estas lineas es preguntar si el usuario abrio el modal, selecciono una carpeta le dio al boton aceptar y esta ruta no esta vacía, si todo esto es verdadero entonces pongo su valor en el campo de texto que tengo en la ventana de mi formulario.

Buena suerte y espero que te funcione ya lo probé y me funciona.

Answer (score 1):

Usa la clase `FolderBrowserDialog` de `windows.forms`:

```
using (var dialog = new System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog())
{
    System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult result = dialog.ShowDialog();
    if(result == DialogResult.OK) 
    {
        string ruta = dialog.SelectedPath;
    }
}
```